# How can I set column width in gtk c#?

Tags: c#, treeview, gtk, monodevelop

Here is my code in TreeView in gtk. Please help me im new to gtk

```
Gtk.TreeViewColumn activeColumn = new Gtk.TreeViewColumn ();   
activeColumn.Title = "Active";   
activeColumn.Expand = true;   
activeColumn.Sizing = TreeViewColumnSizing.Fixed;   
activeColumn.MinWidth = 100;   
Gtk.CellRendererPixbuf activeCell = new Gtk.CellRendererPixbuf ();  
activeColumn.PackStart (activeCell, true);  
activeColumn.AddAttribute (activeCell, "pixbuf", 6);
```

Comment: Can you post complete code ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set column width in Gtk TreeView c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34331345/how-can-i-set-column-width-in-gtk-treeview-c)